# Should I put (a) before an adjective for noun that is singular?

Tags: articles, adjectives

> I wouldn't mind having friends from *a different age category*.

"a different age" is an adjective for "category".

Do we say "*a* different age category" or  "different age categories"?

What is the difference between the two expresions?

Comment: As ever, the singular is for a single age category, the plural for several categories. For example you want teenage friends, thirty-something friends, and pensioner friends.

Comment: another sentences about a >>> can I say providing a comfort or providing comfort why? about singular also @WeatherVane

Answer (score 5):

I think that the thing that will help is to imagine the sentence without the adjective and decide if an article is necessary - here's a simpler sentence.

> I wouldn't mind having a house.

We use "a" before "house" because we need an article for the noun... similarly, if we use an adjective, while it's coming between the article and the noun, the article is still necessary -

> I wouldn't mind having a green house.

The adjective doesn't affect this.

Your example is a bit different because it's not as simple to form without the adjective, or at least, it changes the meaning significantly. Regardless, the correct sentence would be -

> I wouldn't mind having friends from a category.

If you omit "a", then the singular isn't correct. That said, there's nothing wrong with making your example plural, though there's a subtle difference in meaning:

> I wouldn't mind having friends in different age categories.

Means that you want friends in many age categories - some younger than you, some older, some much older. The singular can, in some cases, imply that you want only one other category:

> I wouldn't mind having friends in a different age category.

So, this could mean that you are in the 20-30 age group and want friends in only one other, say 30-40. That said, many people wouldn't restrict it to the singular.

In the end, both options are correct but do make certain to use the article with the singular form!

---

As a note, I'd find it more natural to use "age group" rather than "age category" unless you were specifically calling out categories using that terminology.

Comment: would "having friends **of** a different **age**" work?

Comment: Sure. There's a lot of different ways this could be stated. The plural works there, too - "*... having friends of different ages.*" That said, age is specific to years, where as age categories (or perhaps more colloquially "age groups") is wider, often 5-10 years or so.

Answer (score 4):

No, there can usually be only one specifier in a noun **phrase**.

You proposed parse as *[a different age] [category]* doesn't make sense. It parses semantically as *[a different] [age category]*. But either way, there can be at most one article for the whole phrase.

You can certainly say *different age categories*, and this refers to more than one age category, and usually means that they are different from each other; but if the context has already mentioned an age category (the only context in which the singular *a different age category* would make sense), then it might mean "different from the categories we have previously considered".

Answer (score 1):

To be brief, "a different age category" and "different age categories" are both correct, with one singular and the other plural. And yes, you do need the article in the singular case.

I do want to correct one thing. The adjective is not "a different age". Instead, it works like this: "Category" is of course a noun. "Age" is another noun modifying "category" - nouns can modify other nouns. So an "age category" is a thing - a category specified by a range of ages.

The adjective, then, is just "different", and it modifies the noun phrase "age category." And then "a" is the determiner modifying the whole phrase "different age category". Using brackets, the correct parsing is:

a [different [age category]]